# refresh Page at set interval

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise

I have tried a number of different methods for auto refreshing a page at a specified interval.
1. added `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="30">` to page html. It got rejected.
2. Tried content editor web part with a link to a script i found:

```
    <script>
var reloadTimer = null;
var sURL = unescape(window.location.pathname);
function setReloadTime(secs)
{if (arguments.length == 1)
   { if (reloadTimer) clearTimeout(reloadTimer);
       reloadTimer = setTimeout(“setReloadTime()”, Math.ceil(parseFloat(secs)*1000));
   }  
else   { reloadTimer = null;
     window.location=window.location;
     window.location.replace( sURL );
   }
}
setReloadTime(30);

</script>
```

But nothing seems to work. I have a media web part running a .wmv, but it doesn't reset.
Ultimately I am trying to have it refresh so that i can upload a replacement .wmv and have it auto refresh on the page so that we don;t have to clear the cache, etc.

After further testing it seems i need to clear the cache since the presentation doesn't reset until the browser is restarted.

Comment: So add the wmv with a different name and edit the media web part to point to the new file?

Comment: because we are trying to make it so the person can upload a file with the same name and not go through all that